# use KIE workbench's component in my own web app

Tags: java, drools, jbpm, kie, kie-workbench

I read this [article](https://pefernan.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/embedding-process-forms-on-your-applications-i/) and I  understand that we can use iframe tag to call a KIE workbench's in an external web app.

I want to find a way to insert the Process Model in an external web app(like in the picture). Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: Huan, is it possible to be explicit in the question itself, and instead of providing the link - posting the laconic and short information here. The link will go dead after certain period of time...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access the Process Model image, as an SVG. To allow this feature in jbpm, you have to edit the /org.kie.workbench.KIEWebapp/profiles/jbpm.xml file in the jbpm-console.war by searching for `storesvgonsave` and change the enabled value to true:

```
<storesvgonsave enabled="true"/>
```

After this, when you edit the Process Model in the KIE Workbench and save the model, an additional SVG file will be automatically generated.

Note: I noticed this feature doesn't work in all jbpm versions, for example I had issues with 6.3.0, but it was fine in 6.4.0. Also sometimes I have to manually delete the SVG file in the KIE Workbench, and only save the model after that, because it wasn't generating the current SVG file...

In my case, the KIE Workbench is connected to the same datasource as my own webapp, which uses the deployed kjar as a dependency. In this configuration, when my webapp starts a process instance, the KIE Workbench is able to monitor it and can serve a process instance specific SVG file. This image is process instance specific, because the active nodes of the process model SVG has red color, while the completed notes are greyed out. You can access this process instance specific SVG image in this URL:

[http://{jbpm-console-path}/rest/runtime/{deploymentId}/process/{processDefinitionId}/image/{processInstanceId}](http://%E2%80%8Bhttp://%7Bjbpm-console-path%7D/rest/runtime/%7BdeploymentId%7D/process/%7BprocessDefinitionId%7D/image/%7BprocessInstanceId%7D)

You need to replace the values in this URL. The deploymentId is the GAV Id of your deployment. The processDefinitionId is the ID of your Process Model, while the processInstanceId is a numeric unique ID of the process instance.

If you want to access only the Process Model SVG file, then you should simple leave the /{processInstanceId} from the end of the URL.

You can include the SVG image in your webapp like this:

```
<object id="svgObject" type="image/svg+xml" data="svgURL"></object>
```

Where the `data` attribute should contain the right URL to the SVG file.